# server has gone away php mysql connexion error

Tags: php, mysql, connexion

I have a problem when I try to log to my database with php. I have a website in php and I need to use a database so I have file where I try to connect :

```
       $db = new PDO('mysql:host=IP;dbname=DB_Name', 'Username', '********');
   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   return $db;
```

Then I have an error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: Packets out of order. Expected 0
> received 1. Packet size=78 in /var/www/html/index.php:6 Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/index.php(6): PDO->__construct() #1 {main} Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away in
> /var/www/html/index.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(6):
> PDO->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line
> 6

My database is on a VPS. The database is installed on it with my php code.

I already looked on internet for solution but nothing changed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there anything that you're doing while it fails? A long running query/script, doing a lot of queries at a time? And what php and mysql/mariadb versions are you running?

Comment: I have one query in my page and the rest is html/php code. The version of my php server is PHP 7.4.3, Server version: 10.3.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

if you’re getting the Packets out of order error in the PHP log, there’s an high chance that the issue is due to the fact that there’s an incompatibility between the PHP and MySQL versions you’re using. If upgrading them is not an option, you could try to add the following statement to the PHP script that causes the issue:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

Comment: I tried to add your statement to my php script but it does not work. The version of my php server is PHP 7.4.3, Server version: 10.3.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu 20.04 and

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this may help...

[screenshot of "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  '%timeout%'"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PSNk.png)